# Repeater Connected but no Internet Connection

Tags: networking, internet, repeater

I have a router and I want to connect it to my repeater.

My Router IP is `192.168.1.1`, So I set my repeater using static IP 192.168.1.50 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1. DHCP is auto.

I can connect using laptop or mobile phone, but no internet connection.

[image: Repeater Log]

Comment: It says there was a DNS error, so check if it's a DNS issue. Open a command prompt window and type `ping 8.8.8.8`. Do you get a response?

Comment: Why is it using a DHCP server? you may just have a routing issue with that config. The root AP (probably also your DHCP server) should be the only DHCP server on the network - you don't want to double up on that particular service unless you know exactly what you are doing and you have a very good reason to do so (eg, VLANs or something else more complicated).